# Single quotes in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a syntax of command as

```
command 'variable'
```

The variable has to be passed in single quotes.

Now when i am using a for loop with input file as

```
variable1
variable2
variable3
```

---

```
for i in `cat $1`
do
       command '$i'
done
```

---

```
shell>file.sh input
```

---

The single quote is not intact as bash is not taking input as variable
Please suggest how to keep the variable intact with single quotes

Comment: please do formating your codes by selecting codes and thrn press Ctrl+k

Comment: Which single quotes are we discussing? The back quotes same as `$(command)` or the apostrophe 'hello'?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor please don't change the OP's example code. It's not great, for sure, but it's what they're using. Suggest better alternatives either in an answer or as a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Anything that is enclosed in single quotes will be passed exactly as you type it. So `command '$i'` will pass a string consisting of the two characters `$` and `i` to the command.

You should use double quotes to get the variable's value used instead

```
for i in `cat $1`
do
       command "$i"
done
```

Or, since your code expects a single word per line in your file, replace the entire loop with this single line:

```
xargs -n1 -r command <"$1"
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Roajma but the variable has to be in single quotes else it will fail.

Comment: @Vishal if you put the variable in single quotes its name (and the leading `$`) will be treated as a literal string. If you're getting failures with my suggested code it would help tremendously to see an example of the data in your source file.

Comment: Hereis a SAP command for index rebuild:   brspace -c force -p initPRD.sap -s 20 -l E -u / -f idrebuild -i 'index_name'    [Index_name has to be in single quotes if we simply use " " in bash it will be come as] brspace -c force -p initPRD.sap -s 20 -l E -u / -f idrebuild -i index_name [which will fail my index rebuild command as index_name had single quotes missing]

Comment: @Vishal I have no idea what that's supposed to say. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/440880/edit) to show your new information.

Answer (score 1):

This might do as requested:

```
while read i
do
       command "'$i'"
done < "$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call `command` for each line of a file (whose path is stored in `$1`), with the content of the line passed verbatim as one single argument to `command`, then you'd use:

- With GNU `xargs`:

  ```
  xargs -d '\n' -n 1 -r -a "$1" command
  ```
- With POSIX shells:

  ```
  while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
    command "$line" 3<&-
  done 3< "$1"
  ```

Your

```
for i in `cat $1`; do
  command '$i'
done
```

beside the obvious problem that it passes a literal `$i` string to `command` has several other problems:

- You forgot to quote `$1`, which means it is subject to split+glob which means it wouldn't work properly for file paths that contains spaces, tabs, newlines or wildcard characters
- You forgot the `--` to mark the end of options to `cat` which means it wouldn't work properly for file paths that start with `-`. Even with `cat -- "$1"`, it wouldn't work for a file  called `-`. `cat < "$1"` would be better. Note that if your `command`  also accepts options, you may also need to use `--` there (`xargs ... command --` or `command -- "$line"`)
- That `` `cat $1` `` invokes the split+glob operator again. So it's not looping over the lines of the file but over the list of files that match each of the glob patterns that result of the splitting of the content of the file.

Comment: Reviewing that `while` loop, the purpose of using `<3`, (instead of just `<`), is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command, without quotes:

```
for i in `cat $1`
do
       command $i
done
```

With single quote `'$i'`: you get literally `$i`.

With double quote `"$i"`: you get the values in `$i`, but as a single string (which is usually the desired behaviour).

Without quotes `$i`: this will expand as the value in `$i`, but than the arguments are split. So, if you have a space, e.g. `-a -b`, with double quote you have an argument `-a -b` which is not normally expected, but in the last case, you will have `-a` and `-b` as two different arguments.

I should advise you, that not using quotes is often a security issue, so you should do that only if you really know that inputs is not malicious.

Comment: Hereis a SAP command for index rebuild: 
brspace -c force -p initPRD.sap -s 20 -l E -u / -f idrebuild -i 'index_name' 
[Index_name has to be in single quotes if we simply use " " in bash it will be come as] 
brspace -c force -p initPRD.sap -s 20 -l E -u / -f idrebuild -i index_name 
[which will fail my index rebuild command as index_name had single quotes missing]
In short, my SAP commands needs value passed in single quotes. Please help to achieve that as i need to automate certain tasks

Comment: Sorry I do not understand. Please edit your question and add that sentence, reformatted and in a less concise way. Is the above command the `command` in your question? Where is `$i`? We can solve only problems that are in the question.

Comment: Why `index_name` should be in single quote? Shell will remove quote in any case. Of index_name is a string with spaces?